# Find and replace IDs in cloned code

Tags: jquery

In my HTML I have a div with an ID of room-row-1. I have used the following Jquery to create a clone with a new ID of room-row-2

```
//Clone Extra Rooms
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedRoom").length;

$('#add-room').click(function () {
    cloneIndex++;
    $('.add-persons-to-room-wrapper').first().clone()
    .attr("id", "room-row-" + cloneIndex)
    .appendTo('#room-list');
 });
```

This works fine. Within the cloned code there are some elements that still have an Id of room 1 such as:

```
<select name="rooms[]" id="room1" class="form-control">
```

How can I go through the cloned code and replace all occurances of room1 with room2 ? I was thinking of something like:

```
.find("*").each(function() {
    .html().replace("room1","room" + cloneIndex);
}
})
```

but this invalid code.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use so many unique ID's instead of a simple data attribute with classes? `<div data-row="3"></div>`.

Comment: Don't bother with incremental id attributes. They invariably become a maintenance headache - as you've now discovered. Use common classes and traverse by index instead.

Comment: however you do it, using `.html()` is _not_ the right answer.  Serialising the DOM and deserialising it again is a bad idea because it destroys the original element and any event handlers or other data associated with them.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I use ID's purely because that's the way I thought you should do this. I guess I can use data attributes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks Rory. I will look into this. As you can see below I have managed a fix of sorts but I will definitely look at using common classes. Any recommendations on good articles on doing it this way ?

Comment: I don't know of any articles, but here's an updated fiddle showing the logic: http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1002/. You can see that the JS code is much simpler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Yes, much clearer.

One thing I don't understand though is how do you get the value of an individual field if they don't have unique IDs. For example if I clone your example so I have 3 boxes how do I get the sub category of box 2?

Comment: Under what event would you need to find that value?

Comment: In my example people are assigned to a room with each room having a unique ID. When the form is processed I use the ID to know which room a person has been allocated to.

Using the example http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1002/ I don't see how I would identify a particular room.

Answer (score 0):

I have now amended my function as follows:

```
$('#add-room').click(function () {
    cloneIndex++;
    $('.add-persons-to-room-wrapper').first().clone()
    .attr("id", "room-row-" + cloneIndex)
    .find("*").each(function () {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
        }

    })
    ;

});
```

This code was adapted from http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/tfFLt/ and resolves the issue of renaming items as long as the number is at the end of the Id - for example: select id="room1".

I will test out using classes and attributes to see if this still applies.